# Cannot pass variable to object in c# due to protection level

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, encapsulation

I've got this code, and trying to pass two parameters to LatLng (if hardcoded it works fine), but keep getting is inaccessible due to its protection level - on var location = new LatLng...

What is wrong with my encapsulation?

```
namespace SomeApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "App")]          
    public class MapActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MapLayout);

            MapLocationSetup ();

        }

        public void MapLocationSetup () {

            string currentLocationLatitude = Intent.GetStringExtra ("currentLocationLatitude");
            string currentLocationLongitude = Intent.GetStringExtra ("currentLocationLongitude");

            var location = new LatLng(currentLocationLatitude, currentLocationLongitude);
            CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
            builder.Target(location);
            builder.Zoom(18);
            builder.Bearing(155);
            builder.Tilt(85);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment) FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.mapLayout);
            GoogleMap map = mapFrag.Map;
            if (map != null) {
                map.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                //map.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeSatellite;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do the constructor(s) for `LatLng` look like? At a guess, you're supposed to provide two numbers, not two strings.

Comment: What exactly is inaccessible? Can you show the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's LatLng construtor expects a double, and you are passing a string.  This should give you a typecast error, not a protection level error, but that appears to be the basic problem.

```
string currentLocationLatitude = Intent.GetStringExtra ("currentLocationLatitude");
string currentLocationLongitude = Intent.GetStringExtra ("currentLocationLongitude");

double lat = Double.Parse(currentLocationLatitude);
double lng = Double.Parse(currentLocationLongitude);

var location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

Comment: Indeed updating the code solved the issue. I am using Xamarin Studio, maybe thath's the reason why I received wrong error type.